# How to solve the tensorflow's Conv2d layer error: "self.kernel_size[i], IndexError: tuple index out of range"?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm running my programs with `tensorflow 1.8.0` and `keras 2.2.2` 
I have the following model architecture:

```
in1 = Input(name='in1', shape=(None, 1))
in2 = Input(name='in2', shape=(None, 1))
embedding = Embedding(1000, 50)
e_in1 = embedding(in1)
e_in2 = embedding(in2)
cross = Dot(axes=[3, 3], normalize=False)([e_in1, e_in2])
cross = Conv2D(1, 3, activation='relu', name="conv", padding='same')(cross)
```

But arriving at the `Conv2D` layer, I've got the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> > File
> >     "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py",
> >     line 2910, in run_code
> >         exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)   File "", line 1, in 
> >         cross = Conv2D(1, 3, activation='relu', name="conv", padding='same')(cross)   File
> >     "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py",
> >     line 474, in **call**
> >         output_shape = self.compute_output_shape(input_shape)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/layers/convolutional.py",
> >     line 195, in compute_output_shape
> >         self.kernel_size[i], IndexError: tuple index out of range

I saw [here](https://github.com/titu1994/Neural-Style-Transfer/issues/35) solutions related to the keras version, but I don't think it's the same here, because my keras version worked well with another program that uses the same layer `Conv2D`.
 Anyone can give me some tips, please?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I do not know what do you expect from your model but you probably need to reshape the output or the inputs of Dot() in other to obtain the input dimensions required for Conv2D().

Comment: Thanks @DanielGL for the comment, I think that the problem is solved, but I'm not sure if this is correct: I did `cross2 = Reshape((1, 10, 100))(cross)` then `cross3 = Conv2D(1, 3, activation='relu', name="conv", padding='same')(cross2)` there is no error. I choose the shape (1,10,100) to say that I would like to have one 10x100 matrix with only 1 channel. What do you think? is that correct?

Comment: I'm not sure. Complete your example with the inputs (just random arrays of the correct size) and the .fit() function so everybody can understand your problem.